# Domain and range of function and inverse.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm given the function $f(x)=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}$. I found the inverse and it turned out to be $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{ln(x+1)}{2}-\frac{ln(x-1)}{2}$.I need to find the range of $f$ using $f^{-1}$. I assumed that the range of a function is the domain of the inverse. But If I find the domain of $f^{-1}$ this equal to $(1,\infty)$. And by the graph of $f$ is pretty clear that that is not its domain. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the domain of $f^{-1}(x)$ is actually $(1,\infty)$.
The issue that you are facing here is simply that $ln(x)$ can not be negative. If you notice, the range of $f(x)$ is $1\lt x\lt\infty$ AND $-\infty\lt x \lt -1$. This problem can be fixed by adding an absolute value around the inside of both $ln(x)$'s. See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2sobqmzcg2). Note that you will then have some different values because the new function is now between $-1$ and $1$. Another thing that you can do is combine your functions to get $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{\ln(\frac{x+1}{x-1})}{2}$. This would allow negative values to cancel out naturally between the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the expression $\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{2}-\dfrac{\ln(x-1)}{2}$ is equivalent to $\dfrac12\ln\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}$, but in functions topic two functions are equal if **(1)** their expressions be equal and **(2)** their domains remains equal. Here the domain of the first is $\{x:\,x>1\}$ while the second has $\{x:\,\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}>0\}$ and these two set aren't the same.